# How to add Area lights to gltf?

Tags: light, gltf, webgl

I want to export my scene as gltf from blender and use it in my web app with three.js.

I checked "Include punctual lights" when exporting but I read that this only exports Point/Spot/Directional lights.

What about Area lights ? How do I achieve the effect of Area light in my web 3D scene ?

Answer (score 5):

As of April 2021, area lights are [only a proposal for the glTF format](https://github.com/KhronosGroup/glTF/pull/1948). Unless and until they become part of the format, you'd need to recreate the lights in three.js.

One workaround would be to put metadata about the lights onto empties in Blender, as Custom Properties. The custom properties can be exported with glTF "extras", and become available to three.js as `object.userData`, which you can use to construct new objects at runtime.