# How do I export my model with point light in gltf

Tags: lighting, blend-files, gltf

i am trying to export a model in gltf but after export the point lights are not working
after export :[image]

before export [image]

Comment: Are those point lights? In the screenshot they look like area lights to me... and as far as I know (but I might not be up to date), GLTF only accepts point lights, spot lights and directional lights (= sun lights).

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/220032/128477 as for now, it seems that area lights are still not possible to export

Comment: For bloom effects as shown above, see https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/220433/18161